# Is there a site where I could ask for SE data-mining scripts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, data-explorer

I have basically no programming experience, and I essentially want someone to write a data script for me to use the SE data-mining ... thingy.  Is there a site where I can ask kind-hearted (or easy-reputation seeking) individuals to write a script for me?

Comment: We've discussed Date Explorer scripts here on MSE, actually. But for SQL help, Stack Overflow could be of assistance too.

Answer (score 2):

Discussions about queries specific to the SEDE schema [are be on-topic here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+%5Bdata-explorer%5D+query).

Help with [Transact-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) in general is [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) too.

Comment: Thanks - is either preferred / recommended?

Comment: @YEZ: if you have a question about how the schema works, or how to use the extra features, or even help in formulating an approach to querying the database, ask here. If you are stuck expressing the query effectively (say you need to work out how to do a subselect with join or something), Stack Overflow can help you better with the syntax.